# Silent uninstall of teamviewer in powershell won't work with silent arguments, does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Tags: powershell, prompt, silent-installer, teamviewer

I am using Powershell scripts to install and uninstall different programs trough RMM software. Usually those scripts run without a problem but i noticed for teamviewer it gets stuck. I tried the following uninstall commands locally and found out teamviewer gives a prompt even though the arguments in the command are for a silent uninstall.

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" -Argument "/silent" -PassThru

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -passthru
```

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong or what a workaround can be or a different solution?
I found this solution: https://silentinstallhq.com/teamviewer-install-and-uninstall-powershell/
But that is not what i am looking for, i don't want to install a different program just to be able to uninstall TeamViewer silently.

Comment: Unless you need to wait, you don't need start-process:  `& 'C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe' /S`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that command also gives a prompt, it's like teamviewer can't be uninstalled silently with Powershell.

Comment: Powershell doesn't matter.  You need to find the right silent uninstall options, if it has them.

Comment: That is the hard part, finding them, been browsing google for a while and i don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, too. Surprisingly, I never found it solved through google searches but I discovered the fix was quite easy, and it's specific to PowerShell.

```
net stop TeamViewer

c:\program files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe `/S
```

Notes: I like the old CMD `net stop` command because TeamViewer would just restart if I use the PS `stop-process -Name TeamViewer*` command.
Most importantly, in PowerShell, you need to escape the / switch with the PS escape character ` (top-left key, same key as ~). The S is also case sensitive. Must be uppercase.